# Ruby on Rails: uninitialized constant CUSTOMER_KEY (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make my first Ruby on Rails-Application in Windows 8. When calling `rails server`, I get the error: `uninitialized constant CUSTOMER_KEY (nameerror)` after start of the server and the server exits.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you have `CUSTOMER_KEY`. Show us that code please. That is a constant and needs to be assigned a value

Comment: I have written no code. I'm following this instruction:http://ruby-auf-schienen.de/3.2/statische_webseiten.html

Comment: Odd. Are you doing this on AWS or something? Rails has no CUSTOMER_KEY that you need to set (I will be VERY surprised if it does). Then again, I don't know Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give us much information to work with. cd to the root of your Rails app and run:

`grep -r CUSTOMER_KEY .`

This will list any files that contain `CUSTOMER_KEY`.  This will probably lead you to the answer.

Comment: Im getting: ./config/initializers/omniauth.rb:  provider :facebook, CUSTOMER_KEY, CUSTOMER_S
ECRET, {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join('lib/assets/cacert.pem')
.to_s}}}